# Understanding Custom policy XML tags in Identity Experience Framework in azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to create custom policies in Azure AD B2C. From the existing documentation I could not find the clear descriptions for the XML tags that form the policies.  Where can i find the documentation for custom policies XML tags? I am looking forward for creating custom User Journey. Are there any guidelines for creating custom user journeys?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @JeroenHeier, thanks, i have updated the question as suggested. Please review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best, but beta, collection of documentation for custom policies can be found at the following repository:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Documentation

This documentation was drafted for the public preview of "Azure AD B2C Advanced" which, now, is known as Identity Experience Framework.

Comment: Thanks Chris, i will go through this and get back if required, in addition to this are there any other material (video/text) that would help/guide me in creating especially a custom user journey?